# Unable to copy file from projectDir into projectDir. Why?

Tags: gradle

I don't understand why I can't copy file into `projectDir`. Is this directory blocked during execution? For example:

This works:

```
task metadataFile(type: Copy) {
    from projectDir
    into 'aaa' // projectDir+"/aaa"
    include 'myfile.txt'
    rename 'myfile.txt', 'myfile.new.txt'
}
```

but this doesn't (returns IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file):

```
task metadataFile(type: Copy) {
    from projectDir
    into projectDir
    include 'myfile.txt'
    rename 'myfile.txt', 'myfile.new.txt'
}
```

Do I need first to copy file to temporary directory and then move it to `projectDir`? `ant.copy` can be used instead of gradle copy task but this is not the solution.

Comment: If `from 'aaa'` means `/projectDir/aaa`, then the program is treating projectDir as the root folder.
So shouldn't `from projectDir` mean `/projectDir/projectDir`?

Comment: `projectDir` is predefined gradle variable which points to build.gradle dir.